# List width 100% with overflow not working Bootstrap 3

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a list with `width 100%`, it has divs with cols. It is in another div with `width 100%` because it has `col-xs-12`.
Here is the code.

```
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12">
  <div class="block-gray p20">
    <div class="list list-img-odd">
      <div class="header">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-xs-1 col-sm-1"></div>
          <div class="col-xs-3 col-sm-3">Title</div>
          <div class="col-xs-2 col-sm-2">Title</div>
          <div class="col-xs-2 col-sm-2">Title</div>
          <div class="col-xs-2 col-sm-2">Title</div>
          <div class="col-xs-2 col-sm-2">Title</div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row-list">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-xs-1 col-sm-1">
            <div class="image right">image</div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-xs-3 col-sm-3">
            <div class="name">info</div>
            <div class="col-xs-2 col-sm-2">info</div>
            <div class="col-xs-2 col-sm-2">info</div>
            <div class="col-xs-2 col-sm-2">info</div>
            <div class="col-xs-2 col-sm-2">info</div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I need to overflow-x it in mobile < 768 because it's a "table" and it doesn't fit. When the container is px like col-sm-12 (width 760px) there's no problem but, with the col-xs-12 (width 100%) the table go outside the screen and breaks the layout :(

If I write, for example, the `div list` with style `width 1300px` to make it bigger, and the `div block-gray` with `overflow-x auto`, it doesn't listening... Goes away.

EDIT: If the `div list` has `width 120%` in < 768, for example, it works but I want to know a better CSS writing.

Comment: If it's a "table" then why not use the **responsive table** bootstrap mark up?

Comment: http://getbootstrap.com/css/#tables-responsive

Comment: They didn't use <table> in this project, so... :( I can't change it now. I tried.

Comment: I dont believe it needs to be placed within the col-xs-12 and col-sm-12, so you maybe able to remove this, as its contained within a row

Comment: I don't understand you. Could you please show me?